# still having error for NullPointerException

Tags: java, arrays, class, loops, switch-statement

i tried to tweak [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17111660/418556) and here but still come out error.
the error is when i want to do something with the element inside the array either want to display it, store element or
 searching using index. here is my code:

```
import java.util.*;
public class RegisterMenu {
    private Driver[] newOwner; //array 
    private final int MAX_ITEMS = 30;
    private int size = 0;

       public RegisterMenu(){
        newOwner = new Driver[MAX_ITEMS];
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("1. Register New Car");
        System.out.println("2. Edit Car Information");
        System.out.println("3. Search Car Information");
        System.out.println("4. Display Car List");
        System.out.println("5. Exit");
        System.out.print("Enter Selection: ");
        int s = scan.nextInt();
        switch(s){
            case 1:
                System.out.println("--Register New Car--");
                Driver owner = newReg();
                newOwner[size++] = owner;                
                break;
            case 2:
                System.out.println("--Edit Car Infomation--");
                System.out.print("Enter RegNo to be edit: "); 
                int input = scan.nextInt(); //getting user input of index number which will be edited
                    if(newOwner[input].getName() == ""){
                        System.out.println("No data in RegNo "+input);
                        }
                    else{
                        Driver editOwner = newReg();
                        newOwner[input] = editOwner;
                    }
                break;
            case 3:
                System.out.println("--Search Car Infomation--");
                int index = searchReg();
                newOwner[index].toString();
                break;
            case 4:
                System.out.println("--Display Car Infomation--");
                displayReg();
                break;

            case 5:
                System.exit(0);
            default:
                System.out.println("Error selection");
        }
    }
    public Driver newReg(){ //newReg class for new registration
        Driver owner = new Driver();
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        owner.setRegNo(size+1); //registration number will auto update on each array
        System.out.print("Enter Name: "); //getting info from user and put in setter
        owner.setName(scan.nextLine());
        System.out.print("Enter IC: ");
        owner.setIc(scan.nextLine());
        System.out.print("Enter PlateNo: ");
        owner.carInfo.setPlateNum(scan.nextLine());
        System.out.print("Enter Color: ");
        owner.carInfo.setColor(scan.nextLine());
        System.out.print("Enter Year: ");
        owner.carInfo.setYear(scan.nextLine());
        System.out.print("Enter Make: ");
        owner.carInfo.setMake(scan.nextLine());
        System.out.print("Enter Model: ");
        owner.carInfo.setModel(scan.nextLine());
        System.out.print("Enter Capacity: ");
        owner.carInfo.setCapacity(scan.nextLine());
        return owner; //return all back
    }

    public int searchReg(){ //searchReg will return index number of array
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter Name or Ic to search: ");
        String search = scan.nextLine();
        int dataIndex = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < newOwner.length; i++){
            if(search == newOwner[i].getIc() || search == newOwner[i].getName()){
                dataIndex = i;
            }
        }
        return dataIndex;
    }
    public void displayReg(){ //display all array
        for(int i = 0; i < newOwner.length; i++){
         System.out.println(newOwner[i].toString());
        }
    }
    public static void main (String args[]){
             while(true){
                 RegisterMenu reg = new RegisterMenu();
             }
    }
}
```

`Car` class

```
public class Car {

    public String plateNum; //variable 
    public String make;
    public String model;
    public String color;
    public String year;
    public String capacity;

    public Car(){ //empty constructor
    }

    public Car(String plateNum, String color, String year, String make, String model, String capacity){
        this.plateNum = plateNum;
        this.color = color;
        this.year = year;
        this.make = make;
        this.model = model;
        this.capacity = capacity;
    }
    public String getPlateNum(){  //get 
        return plateNum;
    }
    public String getMake(){
        return make;
    }
    public String getModel(){
        return model;
    }
    public String getColor(){
        return color;
    }
    public String getYear(){
        return year;
    }
    public String getCapacity(){
    return capacity;
    }
    public void setPlateNum(String plateNum){ //setter
        this.plateNum = plateNum;
    }
    public void setMake(String make){
        this.make = make;
    }
    public void setModel(String model){
        this.model = model;
    }
    public void setColor(String color){
        this.color = color;
    }
    public void setYear(String year){
        this.year = year;
    }
    public void setCapacity(String capacity){
        this.capacity = capacity;
    }
}
```

`Driver` class

```
public class Driver {  
   private int regNo; //variable
   private String name;
   private String ic;
   Car carInfo = new Car(); //calling car class

   public Driver(){ //empty constructor

   }
   public Driver(int regNo, String name, String ic, Car carInfo){ //constructor with argument
       this.regNo = regNo;
       this.name = name;
       this.ic = ic;
       this.carInfo = carInfo;
   }
   public int getRegNo(){ //get info 
       return regNo;
   }
   public String getName(){
       return name;
   }
   public String getIc(){
       return ic;
   }
   public void setRegNo(int regNo){ //set from user
       this.regNo = regNo;
   }
   public void setName(String name){
       this.name = name;
   }
   public void setIc(String ic){
       this.ic = ic;

   }
   public String toString(){ //to string for display
       return "RegNo: "+getRegNo()+"\t\tName: "+getName()+"\t\tIc: "+getIc()+
               "\t\tPlateNo: "+carInfo.getPlateNum()+"\t\tColor: "+carInfo.getColor()+"\t\tYear: "+carInfo.getYear()+
                       "\t\tMake: "+carInfo.getMake()+"\t\tModel: "+carInfo.getModel()+"\t\tCapacity: "+carInfo.getCapacity()+"cc";
   }
}
```

Comment: In cases like this, a stack trace is really helpful. Please add it to your question.

Comment: `if(newOwner[input].getName() == "")`. Don't compare content of String using ==.

Comment: as a side note from your problem, you'd better reuse the `RegisterMenu` object, by doing something like: `RegisterMenu reg = new RegisterMenu(); while(true){ reg.interactiveRecordImport(); }` so you avoid reinstanciating that object at each iteration, and for latter improvement, you'll be able to make it store the results in some way.

Comment: would'nt this post better be on [code review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are repeatedly creating new `RegisterMenu` objects in the `main` method

```
while (true) {
   RegisterMenu reg = new RegisterMenu();
}
```

which effectively "wipes" any previous contents of the array `newOwner` here:

```
newOwner = new Driver[MAX_ITEMS];
```

Therefore in `displayReg` the array is empty resulting in the `NPE`. Even if the the array contains *some* elements, there is no check to ensure that the current element is not `null`.

For an immediate fix, you need a use a single instance of `RegisterMenu` and

```
for (int i = 0; i < newOwner.length; i++) {
    if (newOwner[i] != null) {
        System.out.println(newOwner[i].toString());
    }
}
```

but this guard check can be eliminated by using an `ArrayList` instead.

Note: Debuggers in current IDEs are great for sourcing issues such as these

Comment: thank you! this really help me alot! i just put while(true) loop in RegisterMenu() instead in the main method than it work like a champ :)

Answer (score 1):

I can't see a single control over your index variables each time you access your `newOwner` array. Take this example:

```
int input = scan.nextInt(); //getting user input of index number which will be edited
if(newOwner[input].getName() == ""){
```

Are you completely sure the `input` index is related to an existing user? If it isn't, `newOwner[index]` returns `null` and when you invoke `getName` you'll get a NPE.

You're defining the array correctly, but you only create and add new elements on demand:

```
case 1:
    System.out.println("--Register New Car--");
    Driver owner = newReg();
    newOwner[size++] = owner;                
    break;
```

Your first initialization does this:

```
newOwner = new Driver[MAX_ITEMS];
```

Allocating an array of the proper length but filled with `null` elements. You need to make sure that you're not accessing a null owner by, for example, doing a null check before obtaining an element (plus, a range check to avoid an out of bounds exception).